# C3JS - Cannot read property 'category10' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, c3.js

I tried this c3.js code from jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/varunoberoi/mcd6ucge) but it doesn't seem to work in my localhost.

I'm using uniserver as my server. I copy-paste everything but it's not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link href="css/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
        <script src="js/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/c3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function(){
                var chart = c3.generate({
                    data: {
                        columns: [
                            ['data1', 300, 350, 300, 0, 0, 0],
                            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
                        ],
                        types: {
                            data1: 'area',
                            data2: 'area-spline'
                        }
                    },
                    axis: {
                        y: {
                            padding: {bottom: 0},
                            min: 0
                        },
                        x: {
                            padding: {left: 0},
                            min: 0,
                            show: false
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I got when I check the Developer Tools' console is this:

```
c3.js:5783 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category10' of undefined
```

I tried different versions of c3.js but nothing. It's weird because it's working in jsfiddle and not in my local.

Comment: Try to provide the entire absolute path for both libraries. It's also a good idea moving your code to the end of the body.

Comment: After doing some combinations, it turns out it's the d3.js path that is not working. I tried to provide the whole localhost path and C: drive path but it's still not working. The solution I got is to use external url (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js). I don't how it's working like that but, yeah, it's working now. Thanks to your idea. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I solved the exact same JS error on another project by downgrading from D3.js v4 (4.1.1) to v3 (3.5.17).

Comment: @ArtoBendiken, hey, it works! thanks! I would have up vote your comment if I can.

Comment: @JJC Cool! Since it works for you, I added a proper answer so that others who stumble across the issue will be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I solved the exact same JavaScript error on another project by downgrading from D3.js v4 (4.1.1) to v3 (3.5.17).

It turns out that C3.js, as of July 2016, [does not support D3.js v4](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1648):

> It definitely will not work as-is with [D3.js] 4.0. D3 v4 has a totally different namespace and is in no way backwards compatible. Updating to v4 is a very non-trivial task.

Comment: You can get the version here https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v3.5.17? Thanks for your answer, that helped alot.

Comment: If you not using npm and are using the rails gem of D3 adding this code to you gem file will fix the problem `gem 'd3-rails', '~> 3.5.17'`

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/d3-rails/versions/3.5.17

Oh also here is a link to the gem version I am referencing in the comment above.

Comment: Is c3.js version important?

Answer (score 7):

It's because, C3.js is based on D3 v3, and the error occurs when try to run with D3 v4.

The error occurs on below line of code:

```
pattern = notEmpty(config.color_pattern) ?
    config.color_pattern : d3.scale.category10().range()
```

- https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/master/src/color.js#L7

On D3 v4, `d3.scale.category10().range()` should be used as `d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)`, but as C3.js can't be ran on D3 v4 it's meaningless changing this part of code only.

---

If anyone need working with D3 v4+, try https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/.

[billboard.js](https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/) is a forked project of C3.js, having same interface with D3 v4+ support.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the version of C3 you're using doesn't support the version you're using:

```
D3 ver | requires C3 ver
3.x    |  0.4
4.x    |  0.5
5.x    |  0.6
```

Simply make sure you're using the correct version of C3 and you should not see this error.