# Can't get c3 chart to render using Vue.js

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, vuejs2, c3.js

Simple example won't render.  Here is my code:

**main.js**

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var c3 = require('c3');
new Vue({
    template: '<div id="puppa"></div>',
     mounted: function () {
        c3.generate({
            bindto: '#puppa',
            data: {
                type: 'area',
                x: 'x',
                xFormat: '%H:%M',
            columns:[
                ['x',"12:38","12:38","12:38","12:38","12:39","12:39","12:39","12:39","12:40","12:40","12:40","12:41","12:41","12:41","12:41","12:42","12:42","12:42","12:42","12:43","12:43","12:43","12:43","12:44","12:44"],
                ['write', 14709198848,14709313536,14709522432,14709633024,14710034432,14710157312,14710341632,14710583296,14710788096,14710931456,14711058432,14711291904,14711508992,14711668736,14711771136,14712008704,14712107008,14712381440,14712586240,14712795136,14712963072,14713077760,14713331712,14713565184,14713729024],
                ['read', 3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080,3778094080]
            ]
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: function (x) {
                            if (x.getDate() === 1) {
                                return x.toLocaleDateString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: No luck.  How would c3 know what element with that declaration?

Comment: I expect it's because you never actually mount to something. Add an `el: <some div on the page>`.

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML.

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Or whatever other id you want to use. You need to give your Vue an element to render it's template to. In your Vue

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted: function() {
    c3.generate({
      bindto: this.$el,
      ...
    })
  }
})
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qmRRpd?editors=1010).

Also ran across the need to [downgrade the d3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344643/38065) with c3.

Comment: Maybe this is a part of the problem.  I get `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`

Comment: @KingKongFrog Yes, you need to have a div with that id in your HTML. Vue needs to mount to some element.

Comment: Right.  But since I'm setting `template: '<div id="app"></div>'` I'm not sure why I get that error.

Comment: @KingKongFrog No, don't make it the template. The template replaces the element already in your HTML. So, somewhere in your HTML (NOT in javascript) you have a `div#app`, then in your Vue initialization you have  `{el: "#app", template: "<div id="puppa"></div>`, ...}